# QooxDoo: How to force generate.py to include a Part?

Tags: qooxdoo

Now i am building RIA inline application with QooXDoo. I have 2 parts in this inline app.

Now i have a problem in building parts.

How to force the generate.py to include part which is not used explicitly in Application.js

Log from generate.py source

```
>>> Collecting classes   
- Warning: Hint: Unknown global symbol referenced: desktop (tappv3.Application:80)
- Warning: Hint: Unknown global symbol referenced: navSlideIn (tappv3.Application:88)
- Warning: Hint: Unknown global symbol referenced: setDeskTop (tappv3.Application:90)
- Warning: Hint: Unknown global symbol referenced: __MainWindow (tappv3.Application:105)
- Warning: Hint: Unknown global symbol referenced: addWindow (tappv3.MainWindow:30)
- Sorting 262 classes  
>>> Assembling parts
- **part part_agent    - Part #part_agent is ignored in current configuration**
- part boot  
>>> Collapsing parts  
>>> Verifying parts  
>>> Generate application
- Processing 2 locales  
- Generate packages  
- Generate loader script
>>> Done (0m01.51)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the part 'part_agent', this is ignored if the part doesn't contain any classes. You would need to check the part definition of this part in your config.json if it covers valid classes. You might want to review the hints about the "include" key of each part in the [manual](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.0.x/pages/development/parts_using.html#in-depth-configuring-the-include-key-of-your-parts).

You should also check your "Unknown global symbol" warnings.

Comment: thanks. I am using external javascript functions for some additional  tasks. this will makes these unknown global symbol warnings... Is this may cause any problem with it?

Comment: No, if you know the symbols are available at runtime all is fine. But I would #ignore those so that real issues become apparent to you, and don't get drowned between other warnings you can ignore.